# Create a buffer from an array of floating points

Tags: c++, boost, buffer

I'd like to send an array of floats through the network using the Boost libraries. To do so, I have to create a buffer from that array, but it doesn't seem to work.

In this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4/src.html it is done with an array of character but I couldn't replicate with an array of float.

I tried to use this constructor http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload6.html but again I couldn't reach my objective.

```
boost::array<float, 512> arr = { { 0.0f } };
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(arr, arr.size());
```

Now, I'd like to find `0.0f` but from the buffer. I tried to use a `static_cast` but it threw an error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with any errors you get.

Comment: To send stuff over a network you have to send it as bytes. For a `float` it is probably more portable to convert it to text representation first and then send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffers are inherently octet sequences.

You have a big error where you do

```
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(arr, arr.size());
```

because there, arr.size() is in **bytes** (not number of `float` elements). The best way to fix it is to let Boost figure the size out correctly:

```
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(arr); // fixed
```

Now for the rest, it doesn't make a lot of sense to read back the float from the buffer (you still have the array, so why not use that?). But if you **must**, you can using the `buffer_cast`:

```
// extract the first float back - pretend we don't know it's actually the `sending` array
std::cout << "Pi is " << boost::asio::buffer_cast<float const*>(buffer)[0] << "\n";
```

### Demo Time

Let's instead do a demo that

- writes the buffer to a stream
- hex-dumps that stream (to show the actual octets0
- roundtrips it (reading back into *another* array of floats)
- verifies the result

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc471ed93b4f12af)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using Floats = boost::array<float, 10>;

int main() {

    // use a stream to "mock" a communication channel
    std::stringstream ss;

    // fill the stream
    {
        Floats sending = { { M_PI } };
        auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(sending);
        std::copy(buffers_begin(buffer), buffers_end(buffer), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ss));

        // extract the first float back - pretend we don't know it's actually the `sending` array
        std::cout << "Pi is " << boost::asio::buffer_cast<float const*>(buffer)[0] << "\n";
    }

    // for debug only, print the octects representing the stream contents
    {
        auto n = 0;
        for (uint8_t ch : ss.str()) {
            std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch) << ((n++%4==3)?"\n":" ");
        }
    }

    // now let's roundtrip that float buffer!
    {
        Floats roundtrip = { { M_PI } };
        auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(roundtrip);
        std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss), {}, buffers_begin(buffer));

        // now, you can - of course use the buffer_cast again
        std::cout << "Pi is " << boost::asio::buffer_cast<float const*>(buffer)[0] << "\n";

        // but it makes a lot more sense to use the underlying array directly:
        std::cout << "Directly from the roundtripped array: " << roundtrip[0] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Pi is 3.14159
0xdb 0x0f 0x49 0x40
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Pi is 3.14159
Directly from the roundtripped array: 3.14159
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Before I accept it, could you tell me what `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ss)` does in `std::copy(buffers_begin(buffer), buffers_end(buffer), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ss));` as well as what `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss)` does in the last `copy` statement? Thanks

Comment: Those are [just the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator) library [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). Here's a version that avoid that, in case it helps your understanding: [using vector instead of the stream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6975c5e90b756ab6)

Comment: Hey, so I have this function `async_receive_from` that takes as a parameter a `buffer`. I have passed `boost::asio::buffer(data_)` as the parameter, where `data_` is a `boost::array<float, 10> data_;`. Now, it seems that I can't read the data from the `data_` using your solution `boost::asio::buffer_cast<float const*>(buffer)[0]`. I know I'm not doing it right but can't figure the right way to do it. I assume you know understand what I'm trying to achieve : convert a float to a buffer, send the buffer through a socket and then recover the float value from the buffer.

Comment: What's wrong with using `data_.at(0)` or `data_[0]`? If that doesn't give the right result, have you waited for completion, checked the error_code? If that all checks out, are you sending to an identical architecture? Endianness and other representation differences could cause problems (use portable exchange formats, e.g. the idea of simply serializing as text)